# unable to post on route getting object undefined instead of callback in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a favorite route in my application such that if anyone add to favorite then in a the schema the id of the campground is saved in the favorites[]. iam checking first if the campground id is in the array if true then pull the id if not then push in the array then showing in the user profiles. here you can found all files filehosting.org/file/details/859995/project1%20-%20Copy.rar

but everytime it is showing this

```
Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (D:\college\project1 - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as post] (D:\college\project1 - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\college\project1 - Copy\routes\campgrounds.js:135:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\college\project1 - Copy\app.js:20:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

the route code

```
router.post("/:id/favorite", middleware.isloggedin, function(req, res) {
   User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect("/c");
        }

        // check if req.user._id exists in foundCampground.favorites
        var foundUserfavorite = user.favorites.some(function(favorite) {
            return favorite.equals(req.params.id);
        });

        if (foundUserfavorite) {
            // user already favorited, removing favorite
            user.favorites.pull(req.params.id);
        } else {
            // adding the new user favorite
            user.favorites.push(req.params.id);
        }

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.redirect("/c");
            }
            return res.redirect("/c");
        });
    });
});
```

the show.ejs

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
 <form action="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/favorite" method="POST">
    <div class="btn-group">
     <% if (currentUser && user.favorites.some(function (favorite) {
           return favorite.equals(campground._id)
                      })) { %>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> favorited 
          </button>
       <% } else { %>
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> add to favorite 
          </button>
            <% } %>
    </div>
</form>
```

the user schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var plm = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: String,
    avatar: String,
    favorites: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Campground"
    }],
    reputation: { type: String, default: 'noob' },
    rPT: String,
    rPE: Date,
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    isadmin: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
userSchema.plugin(plm);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

middleware

```
var Campground = require("../models/campground");
var Comment = require("../models/comment");
var middlewareo = {};
middlewareo.checkcampowner = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundcaa) {
            if (err || !foundcaa) {
                req.flash("error", "Not Found");
                res.redirect("back");
            } else {
                // console.log(foundcaa.author.id);// console.log(req.user._id);
                if (foundcaa.author.id.equals(req.user._id) || req.user.isadmin) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    req.flash("error", "You Don't Have Permission");
                    res.redirect("back");
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        req.flash("error", "Please Login to Edit")
        res.redirect("back");
    }
}
middlewareo.checkcomow = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        Comment.findById(req.params.comment_id, function(err, foundcomm) {
            if (err || !foundcomm) {
                req.flash("error", "Not Found");
                res.redirect("/c");
            } else {
                // console.log(foundcaa.author.id);// console.log(req.user._id);
                if (foundcomm.author.id.equals(req.user._id) || req.user.isadmin) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    req.flash("error", "Permission Denied");
                    res.redirect("back");
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        req.flash("error", "Please Login");
        res.redirect("back");
    }
}
middlewareo.isloggedin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    req.flash("error", "Please Login!!");
    res.redirect("/login");
};
module.exports = middlewareo;
```

Comment: Can you show your middleware code?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc here you go  the whole project https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/859995/project1%20-%20Copy.rar

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in file /routes/campgrounds.js line 135, change it to:

```
router.post("/:id/favorite", middleware.isloggedin, function (req, res) {
```

your middleware function `isLoggedIn` should be changed to `isloggedin`

just a simple wrong case letter mistake.

a few hints and best practices:

1. just call the index route file in app.js and call others in it
2. isLoggedIn() function exists in passport package. it's easier to use it
3. if you use an IDE it shows you elements that exist on objects and prevents such mistakes
4. pay more attention to your stacktrace on errors, it says error is in campgrounds.js file line 135